# How to capture Ctrl+C in a Python script which executes a Ruby script?

Tags: python, ruby, scripting, ctrl

I am executing a Ruby script from within a Python script. Here is what my Python script "script007.py" looks like:

```
.
.
.
os.system("ruby script.rb") #executing ctrl+c here 

print "should not be here"
.
.
.
```

I execute <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when the Ruby script is running but it just stops "script.rb" and continues with the rest of "script007.py". I know this because it prints "should not be here" when the Ruby script is stopped.

Is there a way that I can catch the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in my Python script even though it happens in Ruby script? Let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Ruby script:

```
trap('SIGINT') { exit 1 }
```

In your Python script, `os.system()` should return the value passed to `exit`. You can use that redirect the flow of control however needed, e.g. call `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 6):

In Python, SIGINT raises [a special exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) which you could catch. If, however, the child consumes the SIGINT signal and responds to it, it does not arrive at the parent process. Then you need to find a different way to communicate from child to parent about *why* the child exited. This usually is the exit code.

In any case, you should start replacing `os.system()` with tools from the `subprocess` module (this is documented, just go and read about this in [the `subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)). You could emit a certain exit code in the child when it exits after retrieving SIGINT, and analyze the exit code in the parent. You can then exit the parent conditionally right after the child process has terminated, depending on what the exit code of the child was.

Example: your child (Ruby program) exits with code 15 after retrieving SIGINT. In the parent (Python program) you would do something in the lines of:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
out, err = p.communicate(...)
if p.returncode == 15:
    sys.exit(1)
print "should not be here"
```